# Spring mvc reinitialize session bean to default value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and i have a bean with session scope. Everything works fine, but when i reenter the url without closing the browser session, i get session bean value of previous request. How can i reset or re initialize the session bean to default value.

Comment: You have a session-scoped bean but you expect it to _not_ retain state through a session?  Perhaps you really want a request-scoped bean?

Comment: No i need the values through out the session, and not just 1 request

Comment: If you re-enter the url without closing browser that means you are using the current session itself which is correct for session scoped bean!

Comment: In your question you say "i get session bean value of previous request" which seems to be what you want according to your comment.